# datasource.groovy pool properties value (maxActive, intialSize...) needs to be hard coded

Tags: grails, groovy, datasource

As I was already getting my database hostname, name, username and password from Amazon Elastic Beanstalk environment variables, I confidently tried to do the same thing for the DBCP pool properties (maxActive, initialSize, ...) :

(my current use case is with AWS, however this question is not related to AWS)

```
// get some properties from Amazon Elastic Beanstalk environment variables
def rdsHostname = System.getProperty("RDS_HOSTNAME")
def rdsDbName = System.getProperty("RDS_DB_NAME")
def rdsUsername = System.getProperty("RDS_USERNAME")
def rdsPassword = System.getProperty("RDS_PASSWORD")
def rdsPoolProps = JSON.parse(System.getProperty("RDS_POOL_PROPS"))

// environment specific settings
environments {
    // ......
    production {
        dataSource {
            pooled = true
            url = "jdbc:mysql://${rdsHostname}:3306/${rdsDbName}"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username = rdsUsername
            password = rdsPassword
            properties {
                jmxEnabled = true
                initialSize = rdsPoolProps.initialSize
                maxActive = rdsPoolProps.maxActive
                minIdle = rdsPoolProps.minIdle
                maxIdle = rdsPoolProps.maxIdle
                maxWait = 10000
                maxAge = 7 * 60000
    // ..................
```

Notice the usage of `rdsPoolProps` in the dataSource's `properties` closure.

When I build the war, I get this error :

```
| Error Error packaging application: Error loading DataSource.groovy: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.parse() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]
Possible solutions: values(), merge(groovy.util.ConfigObject), take(int), plus(java.util.Collection), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), plus(java.util.Map) (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.PackagingException: Error loading DataSource.groovy: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.parse() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]
Possible solutions: values(), merge(groovy.util.ConfigObject), take(int), plus(java.util.Collection), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), plus(java.util.Map)
    at _GrailsPackage$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage.groovy:48)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
    at _GrailsWar$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsWar.groovy:41)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
    at War$_run_closure1.doCall(War.groovy:38)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.parse() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]
Possible solutions: values(), merge(groovy.util.ConfigObject), take(int), plus(java.util.Collection), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), plus(java.util.Map)
    at DataSource.run(DataSource.groovy:13)
    ... 41 more
```

Is there a simple workaround for that ? I would like to do some load tests without having to package and redeploy at each tweaking.

Comment: Are you asking how to change the datasource properties at run time so you can try different settings?

Comment: Only when the application starts.

Comment: The issue really is with the 'properties' closure inside the 'dataSource' closure.

Comment: @florent-blanvillain Can you post full error using --stracktrace as shown in error message

Comment: Done. Thanks for your interest. It doesn't compile when the environment variable isn't set, which is normal because I want the value taken when the app starts.